# How to format table1 values with comma as the thousands separator

Tags: r, html-table

I wonder if someone can help me to format a table1. I need to format my "Sum" continuous values with commas. Code and screenshot below: Thanks in advance

````
```{r}
library(boot) 
library(table1)

melanoma2 <- melanoma
melanoma2$status <- 
  factor(melanoma2$status, 
         levels=c(2,1,3),
         labels=c("Alive", # Reference
                  "Melanoma death", 
                  "Non-melanoma death"))
table1(~ age + thickness | status, render.continuous=c(.="Sum"), data=melanoma2)
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own `render.continuous` function to `format` the values.

```r
library(table1)
library(boot)

table1(~ age + thickness | status, 
       render.continuous = \(x) c("", "Sum" = format(sum(x), big.mark = ",")), 
       data = melanoma2)
```

[image: table1_render_continuous]